# How to get all labels from the state REACTJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a form that get created dynamically  (not really sure how its created) All I know is that I have to clear this form.

What I have done sone far:

```
  ...
  resetForm: function() {
    this.updateValue('ID', '');
    this.updateValue('field_1', '');
    this.updateValue('field_2', '');
    this.updateValue('field 3', '');
    this.updateValue('FIELD4', '');
  },
  ...
```

I know that I don't want to have to manually type in each field name. 
I know in the console I can do `this.state.fields` and I get a array of objects. What I would like to do is get the label element for each array value.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use state to keep elements, use the ref prop `<div ref={r => this.refLabel = r}>content</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like

```
resetForm: function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.fields.length; i++) {
    this.updateValue(this.props.fields[i].label, '');
  } 
},
```

I hope that this helps:

Happy Hacking